# Java Source Folders Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex

I recently got a job at a company which uses the Flash Builder Eclipse IDE for Flex and Java. I have come to accustom the way that they implement their source folders in terms of layout.

As you can see illustrated by number 2, the new package 'flexmonster.data' is illustrated as a separate folder, instead of having 'flexmonster', then on a new line, 'flexmonster.data'.

[image]

I was wondering if this type of data structuring can be formatted into Eclipse Juno. I like the cleanliness of the code more and the reduced amount of 'spam' created by the huge blocks of packages.

Thanks

Comment: If anyone knows it will be JonSkeet. >_> 
Batman of StackOverflow.

Comment: Feel free to post as an answer and I will get my friends to come in here and karma-whore that forever lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not running that version of Eclipse, but it's likely to be the same.

Near your [ 1 ] arrow is a down arrow icon.  From there you can find "Package Presentation" - you want 'Hierarchical'.

[image: hierarchical packages]